# Unable to restore a VM in Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012

Tags: hyper-v

for some unknown reason  I can no longer find the VHDX file of my VM in the host's disk.  I did find however a BIN file and VSV file, is it possible to restore the lost VHD from these two files?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. Those two files comprise the Saved State of the VM but I don't think you can use them to recover the VHD file. Have you searched the host (or your VM storage location) for *.vhd to try and locate the VHD file?

Comment: yes, put the host upside down for that VHD file.  Thank you for your answer

Comment: under the settings for the VM, it should indicate the path where the VHD existed at some point, so if you weren't sure where to look, that would be a good place to start.  (I know this is old, but I felt this might help someone else.)